# @Conditional on bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, conditional-statements, autowired

I have been searching for this for a while.

Till now, I found [this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/) blog very useful but did not solve my problem.

I want to `@Autowired` a bean only if a `flag` is true, else I want that to be `null`

**Use Case:**

If one of the DB is under maintenance, I do not want my app to fail.

```
@Bean("sqlDatabase")
public Database getSqlDatabase(@Value("${datasource.sql.url}") String url,
        @Value("${datasource.sql.username}") String username, @Value("${datasource.sql.password}") String password,
        @Value("${datasource.poolsize.min}") int minPoolSize, @Value("${datasource.poolsize.max}") int maxPoolSize,
        @Value("${database.enable-sql}") boolean isSqlEnabled) {
    if (isSqlEnabled)
        return Database.builder().url(url).pool(minPoolSize, maxPoolSize).username(username).password(password)
                .build();
    else
        return null;
}
```

Now, in this case, its throwing error as I cannot `autowire` a `null` bean.

I wanted to use `@Conditional` but my case is a bit complex. I already need all 3 databases to be updated. I just want to `skip` one of them if conditions are not met.

Comment: *I already need all 3 databases to be updated. I just want to skip one of them if conditions are not met.*. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by this?

Comment: I have a spring boot application which touches 3 databases. I am creating 3 different beans for those. now lets say for maintenance, we want to switch off one db, I will still be needing rest 2. In the example in the blog. It is `EITHER-OR` which really is not applicable in my case. I just don't want my initialization hung up with timeouts trying to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use profiles.
One profile for every database

- db1
- db2
- db3

Than annotate the bean class or the bean method with the profile that must be activated to use that bean like

```
@Profile("db1")
@Bean("db1")
public Database getSqlDatabase(...){...}
```

When you start your app, beans annotated with @Profile will only be created, if the regarding profile is activated.

You activate a profile by setting the property 'spring.profiles.active'.
To activate db1 and db2 :

```
spring.profiles.active=db1,db3
```

You can set that property in a properties file or as a command line parameter.

Profiles give you a lot of flexibility to change you spring context by configuration

- you can annotate many beans with the same profile
- you can annotate a configuration class with a profile
- you can use profile specific property files
- you can use many profiles in one @Profile annotations. Logical 'or' will be used, so a bean annotated with @Profile("db1","db2") will be created if profile 'db1' is active or profile 'db2' is active

  - if you want something else than 'or' you can use @Conditional to define your own logic

**Please note : If you use do not use component scan or xml configuration, the annotation @Profile at a bean class has no effect. You need to annotate the bean method with @Profile or the whole configuration class instead.**

Comment: what happens when I have the fields annotated? will it be null if it does not satisfy the profile?

Comment: as I suspected, it autowires the bean as `null`. Exactly what I need !! I can handle the rest. Thanks a lot. I was confusing a lot of things unnecessarily. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can leverage `@Conditional` property during the `initial component scan` to **avoid error** while initializing based on the **environment properties**.

A valid use case would be enable a repository to be scanned for bean initialization when the environment `db.enabled` property is `true`

example:
https://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/

**Conditional helper class**

```
public class DocumentDBInitializerPresence implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        DocumentDBInitializerInfo employeeBeanConfig = null;
        try {
            employeeBeanConfig = (DocumentDBInitializerInfo)context.getBeanFactory().getBean("DocumentDBInitializerInfo");
        } catch(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
            System.out.println("BEAN NOT FOUND:: " + employeeBeanConfig != null );
        }
        System.out.println("BEAN FOUND :: " + employeeBeanConfig != null );
        boolean matches = Boolean.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("db.enabled"));
        System.out.println("CONFIG ENABLED :: " + employeeBeanConfig != null );
        return employeeBeanConfig != null && matches;
    }
}
```

**Using in service**

```
@Service
@RefreshScope
@Conditional(value= DocumentDBInitializerPresence.class)
public class RepositoryDocumentDB {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RepositoryDocumentDB.class);

    public static final String DOCUMENT_DB_LOCAL_HOST = "localhost";
    DocumentDBInitializerInfo documentDbConfig;

    @Autowired
    public RepositoryDocumentDB(final DocumentDBInitializerInfo documentDbConfig) {
        this.documentDbConfig = documentDbConfig;
    }
}
```

This will not throw error on application startup if you are not autowiring
**RepositoryDocumentDB** anywhere yet and the **db.enabled** is set to false.

Hope this helps!